# Download excel file in angular 7

Tags: excel, angular, file, download

Hey after struggling to download the excel from server below is the solution i found very easy.But API side they will just read the path and send the files.
How can i differentiate the file type?

If server files are in your project directory or server , we would like to down load the excel or any file directly. Added the below implementation which works only for excel.

**API(.net):**

```
public ActionResult Download()
    {
        string fileName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filename"];
        var filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + fileName);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            var response = new WebServiceStatus()
            {
                code = -1,
                data = null,
                message = "File is Not available"
            };
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
            return HandleTrivialHttpRequests(data);
        }

    }
```

**Angular V7**
//Declaration

```
headers: HttpHeaders;
options: any;
```

//Constructor or u can have for specific method

```
this.headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
this.options = {
    observe: 'response',
    headers: this.headers,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
};
```

//Service request:

```
this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/api/report', this.data, 
this.option)
 .pipe(
catchError(err => this.handleError(err))
).subscribe(response => {
    Helper.exportExelFile(response, 'FileName');
});
```

//In component or in helper function in one class, I have used helper 
 function which can be reused in other places also

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
function exportExelFile(data, filename) {
 const blobValue = new Blob([data['body']], {
 type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
   });
   FileSaver.saveAs(blobValue, filename + '.' + FileType.EXCEL);
 }

 export const Helper = {
 exportExelFile
 };
```

Comment: Is there a question here? Or does it respond to a previous question - if it does it should be posted as an answer to that question.